# Jenkins - discard specific artifacts from older builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Is it possible in Jenkins to only delete specific artifacts created by a build job?

In my situation I create 4 artifacts - 3 of which are 2kb .txt files and one of which is 0.5gb tar.gz.  I'd like to keep the 3 smaller artifacts indefinitely, but aggressively remove the tar.gz artifacts after 5 builds.

Using logrotator this doesn't seem to be an option (it can only remove all artifacts or none) but I was hoping there might be a way to write a Groovy library that could be called after each new build, or a pluggin that could handle this for me?

See: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/tasks/LogRotator.html

Does anyone have any pointers on how to get started with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely **remove build artifacts directly on filesystem level**.

If you want to trigger this directly from within Jenkins, the easiest way is probably to write a **Groovy post-build script** that takes care of the deletion.